# How to overlap images in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to design as attached screenshot

[image]

I tried using RelativeLayount and AbsoluteLayout but Still not successful to have the required result. Can you help

```
<RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">

            <Image Source="XX.png"  />
            <Image Source="YY.png"/>
            <Image Source="WW.png"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

These are the three images

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't see anything in that image that appears to be overlapping?

Comment: @Jason I added a schreenshot of how it looks on the simulator now

Comment: I still have no idea what you are trying to do.  What are XX, YY and WW?  Is the image of the hand holding the device actually one of the images you are working with?

Comment: there are three different images. I included the images to make it clear

Comment: ah, OK.  Using a RelativeLayout without specifying any kids of constraints won't do much. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AbsoluteLayout and specify image positions to make them overlap:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
        <Image Source="aa.png" Aspect="Fill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,1,1"/>
        <Image Source="bb.png" Aspect="Fill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,1,1"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

But in your case, it will be difficult to adjust the positions since your images are of different scale, and are not symmetrical, it's recommended that you make some adjustment on your images first so that it will be easier for you to put them into the screen.

For more information about AbsoluteLayout, see [Xamarin.Forms AbsoluteLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout)

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 - Use grid with same Row and Column
Option 2 - Use AbsoluteLayout